# WKWebView loading embedded movies results in full screen play

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, ios13, swift5

I have a `WKWebView` in my app that calls a site and loads movie files that all require HTTP Basic auth. I've implemented `public func webView(_: WKWebView, didReceive: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {` which works correctly.

However, the movies embedded in other pages sometimes go to full screen plays, as if the challenge response was causing a redirect. At least, that's my hypothesis... the same behavior does NOT happen in mobile Safari.

How can I prevent this full screening behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WKWebView` does not play inline media on iPhone by default. I needed to pass in a `WKWebViewConfiguration` at init time:

```
let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
configuration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
self.webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: configuration)
```